Numbers 31:40 explanation of the 32 virgins
Are there references of what the 32 virgins dedicated to God delivered to Eleazar from the Midianites defeat used for?
It's understandable the ones given to the Levites that they will be married off.
Since the priests were only 2 with their children, does it mean they married them off to their children?
With this scenario, it means the midianites are part of the bloodlines of the priest and Levites,  right?

Not any easy question.

First, the literal rendering of Num 31:40 is:

And the persons 16000; and tribute to YHWH is 32 souls

There is no indication that these were either male or female, much less whether virgin of not.  They were just people.  However, notice the following table:



Total plunder, Num 31:32-35
Plunder for Soldiers Num 31:36-40
Plunder for Eleazar Num 31:36-40




675,000 sheep
337,500 sheep
675 sheep


72,000 cattle
36,000 cattle
72 sheep


61,000 donkeys
30,500 donkeys
61 donkeys


32,000 virgins
16,000 people
32 souls



Thus, while V40 does not specifically say that 16,000 people and 32 souls were virgins, the contexts very strongly suggests this as rendered by the NLT.
The purpose/destiny of such people would have been a combination of wives and personal servants/slaves.
That Midianites were part of the "bloodlines" of the Israelites generally and of the Levites in particular should not surprise anyone - many foreigners were absorbed into the Israelite nation - here is a sample:

The unfortunate story in Gen 38 about Judah and Tamar shows that a foreigner became the mother of the tribe of Judah.
When Jacob entered Egypt, his family numbered 75 people (Acts 7:14, Ex 1:5).  Some of these were not direct descendants of Abraham such as the wives of the 12 patriarchs, notably Joseph’s own wife.  215 years and four generations later at the exodus, Israel’s army had over 600,000 men, excluding women and children, (Ex 12:37, Num 1:46, etc) suggesting a total population of several million people, requiring many additions.  This included a significant mixed multitude (Ex 12:38) showing that Israel obviously consisted of many non-biological Jews had joined.  (Note that it is biologically impossible for Israelite numbers to have grown from 75 to several million biologically without many outside additions.)
Moses married a Midianite (Ex 2:16-21) also known as a Cushite.  Miriam and Aaron were severely reprimanded and punished for displaying racism (Num 12:1, 2)
Caleb, who represented and led the tribe of Judah was a Kennizite (Num 32:12).
Rahab was a Canaanite (Josh 2:1, 2, Matt 1:5)
Ruth was Moabite (Ruth 1:4 16, 17, Matt 1:5) – these last two make King David descended from foreigners (Ruth 4:13-16).
Uriah was a Hittite (2 Sam 11:3)
King David’s elite personal regiment consisted of Gittites, that is, Philistines (2 Sam 15:18-22, 1 Chron 18:17)
Isa 14:1 - When the LORD has compassion on Jacob and again chooses Israel, and settles them on their own land, then strangers will join them and attach themselves to the house of Jacob.
Isa 56:6, 7 - And the foreigners who join themselves to the LORD to minister to Him, to love the name of the LORD, and to be His servants— all who keep the Sabbath without profaning it and who hold fast to My covenant—I will bring them to My holy mountain and make them joyful in My house of prayer.  Their burnt offerings and sacrifices will be accepted on My altar, for My house will be called a house of prayer for all the nations.”  See also V3.
The Rechabites were Kenites (Jer 35:1-19)
Many other foreigners lived in Israel (1 Chron 22:2, 17, 2 Chron 30:25)
In Esther’s time “many of the people of the land became Jews” (Esther 8:17, 9:27)


2 Kings 5:2 may give us a hint.  The young girl became the wife's servant.
